# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') at <Jasmine>

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am creating a test for clear Item, but when I run the test I get the error of
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') at "

How can I arrange to run filter in the test?

My function:

```
clearItem = (item, key) => {
        this.form[key] = this.form[key].filter(el => el !== item);
        this.chipsOptions = this.chipsOptions.filter(el => el !== item);
    }
```

My test:

```
describe('clearItem()', () => {
        it('should clear item', () => {
            let item = {id:1, name:'test'};
            component.form = { key: {id:1}, id: 1, name: 'testForm' };

            component.addItem(item);
            component.clearItem(item, {key: { id: 1 }});

            expect(component.form['key']).not.toEqual(item);
            expect(component.chipsOptions['key']).not.toEqual(item);
        });
    });
```

Comment: not sure if your test is right? `.filter` is the Array method, you cant call it on the Object, and second your `clearItem` function key can't be an object, it should be key Name

Comment: Same as `component.form`, you should also initialize `component.chipsOptions` at the beginning of your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` method is defined for **array** objects. Before using `filter` method, try to check the types of objects that you use this method.

```js
console.log(Array.isArray(this.form[key]));
console.log(Array.isArray(this.chipsOptions));
// When both of them are true, then you can use filter.
```

[filter method reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[isArray method reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)